# Show that the graph of $f$ is an immersed manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

$f$ is a smooth function from a smooth manifold $M$ to a smooth manifold $N$, how can I show that its graph, $\{{(x,f(x)) | x\in{M}}\}$ is an immersed manifold of $M \times N$

I think i must show that the inclusion map is an injective immersion and a homeomorphism but I do not know how to do that, how could I compute the jacobian matrix of the inclusion map?

Im kind of lost in differential geometry, any help is welcome

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem and implicit function theorem?

Comment: yes we used them already

Answer (score 0):

you want to show that the inclusion map is an immersion i.e. that the differential of the inclusion has maximal rank. We have that $\Gamma_f$ is given as the inclusion from $M\rightarrow M\times N$ by the map $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$. Since $f$ is smooth the inclusion is smooth.

Now to compute the jacobian of the inclusion map it suffices to do it locally, so that you are looking at the jacobian of the following: lcoally you can write $f:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ then you only need to know what the jacobian of the following map from $\mathbb R^m\rightarrow \mathbb R^m\times \mathbb R^n$ given by $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is (you can do this by standard multivariable calculus).